# Center div without negative margins

Tags: html, css

I have a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/apej60nL/

I have two columns in bootstrap. One column has text as content the other is empty apart from a yellow div that is repersenting an image.

I need to center the yellow div vertically against the text block. To do this I need to make the left div containing the yellow div the same height as the text div.

I have done this with

```
.test .row {
    display: table;
}

.left, .right {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;   
}
```

I positioned the yellow div absolutely and used negative margins to center it.  I can do this because I know the width/height of the yellow div. I need to do this without knowing the width/height. The image/div could be different dimensions.

How can I center it vertically with knowing the size?

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect no width/height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a couple of changes to your CSS to achieve what you're looking for:

```
.left, .right {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;  
    //deleted vertical-align: top;  
}

.left{
    background: red;
    vertical-align:middle; //replaced position: relative; with this
}
.right{
    vertical-align: top; //add this
    background: #ddd;    
}

.block{
    //various changes here, will be centered horizontally and vertically
    background: yellow;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/apej60nL/25/)

Note: if you want to constrain either the width of the `block` div then add a `max-width` style.

Answer (score 4):

Make the top/right/bottom/left positions of the yellow block (image) zero, and the margin auto:

```
.block {
    background: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    height: 150px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
    width: 50px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/apej60nL/11/)**

Comment: Why do you have to set top/left/bottom/right to 0? Seems funny

Comment: @JuanMendes - For a lengthy explanation, check out http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

Comment: Very interesting, though I hope we can start using flex boxes soon to get the same effect without what looks like a hack. Didn't the OP say no hard coded width/height?

Comment: @JuanMendes - the dimenions are just to illustrate. Here's a fiddle with an image instead http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/apej60nL/24/. And the method isn't actually a hack, it's the way absolute positioning is meant to work -- albeit sometimes in surprising ways.

Comment: That's why I said what looks like a hack,  it's not very intuitive. No matter what, it's a way to align vertically once you know it. It just may not be as easy for others to realize what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the width/height, here is an example:

```
.block{
    background: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%)
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%)
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/apej60nL/17/)

Answer (score 1):

`vertical-align: middle` works nicely with table cells, but I had to change the yellow box to `display: inline-block`:

```css
.test .row {
    display: table;
}
.left, .right {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
}
.left {
    background: #F00;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
.right {
    background: #DDD;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.block {
    background: #FF0;
    display: inline-block; /* display changed to inline block */
    text-align: left;      /* text align is inherited so reset it */
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/apej60nL/23/)

Answer (score 1):

see it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var l=$('.left').height()-50;
    var t=l/2;
    $('.block').css('top',t);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/srvnk44/apej60nL/22/

Comment: [Just sayin'](http://zarjay.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/20091116-so-large.gif)

Comment: If the question doesn't mention jQuery (or even JavaScript), you should not use it. The OP is clearly wanting to do this with CSS

Comment: Well, there are plenty of answers with CSS already here so at least it's another option.